# Database modeling troubleshooting

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hi i recently came across a situation where i am asked to optimize data model for one of our client for there already developed and running product.The main reason for doing this exerciser is, the product suffers from performance slowness due to too many locks and too many slow running queries.As i am not a DBA, looking at first site to the data model and doing some tracing of queries, i realize that the whole data model suffers from improper design and storage.The database is **MySQl 5.6** and we are running InnoDB engine on that.

I want to know that is there any tool out there which can analyze the whole data model and can point out to possible issues including data structure definitions,indexes and other stuffs?
I tried lots of profiling tools including Mysql Workbench,Mysql Enterprise Monitor(paid version),jet profiler but they all are seems to be limited to identifying slow queries only. What i am interested in a tool which can analyze the existing data model and report problems with it and possible solutions for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not look at the data model in isolation. You need to consider the data model together with the requirements and the actual data access/update patterns.

I recomend you identify the top X slowest queries and perform your root-cause analysis.
Make sure you focus on the parts of the application that **matters**, i.g. the performance problems that negatively affects the usefulness of the application.

And by data access/update patterns I mean for example:

- High vs low nr of concurrent access
- Mostly reads or updates?
- Single record reads vs reading large nr of records at once
- Access is evenly spread out during the day or in bulk at certain times
- Random access (every record is likely to be selected or updated) vs mostly recent records
- Are all tables equally used or some are more used than others
- Are all columns of all tables read at once? Or are there clusters of columns that are used together?
- What tables are frequently used together?

Answer (score 0):

The slow queries are the most important to look at.  Show us a few of them, together with SHOW CREATE TABLE, EXPLAIN, and how big the tables are.

Also, how many queries per second are you running?

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';

Comment: sorry guys, i understand that without looking at what really is going on its difficult to say.But its confidentioal and i cant share DB model with you.NDA !

Answer (score 0):

There are no such tools as those you are looking for, so I guess you'll have to do your homework, proposing another data model that "follows the rules".

You could begin by getting familiar with the [first three normal forms](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm).

You could also try to detect SQL antipatterns (there are books talking about these) in your database. This should give you some leads to work on.

Comment: Please do not rollback edits to remove links to bootleg ebooks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226326/should-we-add-it-ebooks-info-to-the-stack-overflow-url-blacklist

Comment: Well then please bear with me but I'd better suppress the commercial link to amazon.